# Hive - joining two tables to find string that like string in reference table

Tags: hive

I stumbled in a case where requires to mask data using keyword from other reference table, illustrated below:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOiCt.png): [image]

Table A contains thousands of keyword and Table B contains 15 millions ++ row for each day processing..

How can I replace data in table B using keyword in table A in new column?

I tried to use join but join can only match when the string exactly the same

Here is my code

```
select
sourcetype, hourx,minutex,t1.adn,hostname,t1.appsid,t1.taskid,
product_id,
location,
smsIncoming,
case 
when smsIncoming regexp keyword = true then keyword
else 'undef' end smsIncoming_replaced
from(
select ... from ...
)t1
left join
(select adn,keyword,type,mapping_param,mapping_param_json,appsid,taskid,is_api,charlentgh,wordcount,max(datex) 
from ( select adn,keyword,type,mapping_param,mapping_param_json,appsid,taskid,is_api,charlentgh,wordcount,datex ,last_update,
              max(last_update) over (partition by keyword) as last_modified 
       from sqm_stg.reflex_service_map ) as sub
where   last_update = last_modified 
group by adn,keyword,type,mapping_param,mapping_param_json,appsid,taskid,is_api,charlentgh,wordcount)t2
on t1.adn=t2.adn and t1.appsid=t2.appsid and t1.taskid=t2.taskid
```

Need advice :)

Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to fathom the mapping between your sample data and query columns. Please provide Input data example with column names and desired output

Comment: @leftjoin sorry, i've updated my question

Comment: Is it always located first(at the beginning) in table B column? Is it some non-alpha delimiters like << or + or # like in your example? Or simply if keyword contained in table B column then replace it with keyword?

Comment: yes it's always begin with keyword, but for the delimiters is not specified because it's human input

Answer (score 0):

Use `instr(string str, string substr)` function: Returns the position of the first occurrence of `substr` in `str`. Returns null if either of the arguments are null and returns 0 if `substr` could not be found in `str`. Be aware that this is not zero based. The first character in str has index 1.

```
case 
    when instr(smsIncoming,keyword) >0  then keyword
    else 'undef' 
 end smsIncoming_replaced
```